# Reload Dropdown Box content?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I been all over and nothing worked for me so i had to ask the community if they have anything for me.

So, i have a dropdown and a switch (checkbox) if i press the switch it should load the dropdown content for lets say "Radio" and if i switch it back it should switch the dropdown content back to lets say "playlist".

Below is the code:

```
<?PHP
// Read playlist & Radio
    $playlists =    explode("\n", shell_exec("/usr/bin/mpc lsplaylists"));
    array_pop($playlists); //remove empty last line

    $radioStations  = array();
    $radioStations =    explode("\n", shell_exec("/usr/bin/mpc ls Webradio"));
    $radioStations = str_replace("Webradio/","",$radioStations);
    $radioStations = str_replace(".pls","",$radioStations);
    array_pop($radioStations); //remove empty last line
?>
```

script:

```
<script>

        function checkSelectedScheduleType()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('radioSelected').checked) 
            {
                alert("radio selected fill dropdown with radio stations...");

                <?php 
                $playlist = $radioStations;
                ?>
            } 
            else 
            {
                <?php 
                $playlist = $playlists;
                ?>
                alert("Playlist selected fill dropdown with playlists...");
            }
        }


</script>
```

Switch:

```
<td class="alarmvalue" style="padding:2px 15px;">
        <select name="add[alarmplaylist]" id="playlist_wrongstyle" class="form-control"  style="visibility:visible; background: transparent; width:250px;">
            <?php foreach ($playlist as $playlistss){echo "<option value=\"$playlistss\">$playlistss</option>\n";} ?>
        </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue that i found:

Even though the PHP was inside the JS "IF" statement, the php was still running without the JS function being called which was strange and so the select was assigning the last php variable.

My fix:

Might not be the best but worked! I created another dropdown, populated that with my desired options and then made Display="none" and then when i do click it will trigger my function with "onchange" and make it Display="block" and hide one another and is working perfectly!

Code below:

JS:

```
<script>
        function checkSelectedScheduleType()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('radioSelected').checked) 
            {
                document.getElementById("slplaylist").style.display="none";
                document.getElementById("slradio").style.display="block";
            } 
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("slplaylist").style.display="block";
                document.getElementById("slradio").style.display="none";
            }
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<td class="alarmvalue" style="padding:2px 15px;">
        <label class="switch-lightp2 well_" onchange="checkSelectedScheduleType()">
            <input id="radioSelected" name="" type="checkbox" value="">
            <span><span>Playlist</span><span>Radio</span></span><a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
        </label>
    </td>

    <td class="alarmcat">

    </tr>

    <td class="alarmvalue" id="slplaylist" style="padding:2px 15px; display:block;">
        <select name="add[alarmplaylist]" id="playlist_wrongstyle" class="form-control"  style="visibility:visible; background: transparent; width:250px;">
            <?php foreach ($playlists as $playlist){echo "<option value=\"$playlist\">$playlist</option>\n";} ?>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td class="alarmvalue" id="slradio" style="padding:2px 15px; display:none;">
        <select name="add[alarmplaylist]" id="playlist_wrongstyle" class="form-control"  style="visibility:visible; background: transparent; width:250px;">
            <?php foreach ($radioStations as $playlist){echo "<option value=\"$playlist\">$playlist</option>\n";} ?>
        </select>
    </td>
```